# Can't change LaF JMenu "buttons"

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jmenu

As I'm modifying an existing Look and Feel, I also want to change how the "buttons" of a `PopUpMenu` behave. Right now it behaves like this, when I hover my mouse over it. As you can see it behaves very "3D":

[image: 3D Behaviour]

And I want to let it behave like the buttons I made below them:

[image]

I've looked trough alot of documentation of Java Swing but I can't seem to find it. So if someone knows, please help me out. I have tried to change every property I could find.

Comment: You can find it by yourself: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#custom

Comment: @zlakad There is no answer to my question there. I don’t want to change layouts and it doesn’t mention any UIManager options

Comment: I'm not using Swing, but let's suppose you cannot change properties of JMenu in the way you want. Just use some other Swing controls and write proper ActionListeners.

Comment: I’m afraid you’re right. If only I had decided earlier to do this.. I am using Swing btw because JCEF doesn’t support JavaFX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer here is, as I found out, not everything can be managed by the LaF. Therefore, sometimes you have to get your hands dirty.
In this case I created my own `CSTMButton`, because in Swing one is also able to add buttons to a menubar. Now I can create it's own listener to generate the behaviour I want.